# How to average multiple columns within a query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CKBxaRPP9KR6j3Gp24JRpuGOxUbirBuVg3riRcokQXI/edit?usp=sharing

Scroll to the bottom where I have Avg Days to Close and the Speedometers.

I am trying to get the Purchase Closes one (in Cell F500) to average out ColumnBY, ColumnBZ, ColumnCA from the BNTouch Raw Data Sheet using the query.

Here is what I have for the query, found in Cell F500:

```
=Query('BNTouch Raw Data'!$A$1:CN,
if($I$9<>""," 
SELECT Avg(BY),Avg(BZ),Avg(CA)
WHERE BO contains 'Closed' 
 and BD >= date """&TEXT($F$9,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" 
 and BD <= date """&TEXT($F$11,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"""
 and AF = '"&$I$9&"'
LABEL Avg(BY),Avg(BZ),Avg(CA) 'Avg Days to Close' ","
SELECT Avg(BY),Avg(BZ),Avg(CA)
WHERE BO contains 'Closed' 
 and BD >= date """&TEXT($F$9,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" 
 and BD <= date """&TEXT($F$11,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"""
LABEL Avg(BY),Avg(BZ),Avg(CA) 'Avg Days to Close' "))
```

Comment: the link is not working.

Answer (score 1):

To use the aggregate functions you need to use the GROUP BY clause. The sheet you shared is not set to View access, so I am flying somewhat blind here.

```
=Query('BNTouch Raw Data'!$A$1:CN,
if($I$9<>""," 
SELECT Avg(BY),Avg(BZ),Avg(CA)
WHERE BO contains 'Closed' 
 and BD >= date """&TEXT($F$9,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" 
 and BD <= date """&TEXT($F$11,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"""
 and AF = '"&$I$9&"'
GROUP BY <column1>,<column2>, etc.
LABEL Avg(BY),Avg(BZ),Avg(CA) 'Avg Days to Close' ","
SELECT Avg(BY),Avg(BZ),Avg(CA)
WHERE BO contains 'Closed' 
 and BD >= date """&TEXT($F$9,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" 
 and BD <= date """&TEXT($F$11,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"""
LABEL Avg(BY),Avg(BZ),Avg(CA) 'Avg Days to Close' "))
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation_functions

Comment: whoops, this should work. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CKBxaRPP9KR6j3Gp24JRpuGOxUbirBuVg3riRcokQXI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if you group by columns won't it spit out multiple values instead of averaging all columns into one cell?